# Onde esta a base de dados usada pelo IIS

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net, iis

Tenho um projeto criado em c# (ASP.NET 5 MVC) que utiliza uma base de dados SQL.

Publiquei o projeto para uma pasta no servidor local e criei uma base de dados com Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Tudo corre bem no IIS, contudo, a base de dados que está a ser usada pelo IIS não é aquela que eu criei no SSMS. Se eu for ao menu das Cadeias de ligação no IIS consigo ver que esta a apontar para a base de dados que criei, contudo, os dados não estão a ser registados nessa base de dados.

Para tentar perceber o que se estava a passar, apaguei todas as bases da dados que me apareciam listadas no SSMS, no entanto a aplicação continuou a funcionar perfeitamente. Fiz então uma pesquisa na servidor por ficheiros do tipo MDF mas não me apareceu nenhum.

**String de conexão:**

```
<add connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=outraDB;Integrated Security=true" name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Alguém tem ideia do que se esta a passar ?

Comment: Como é feita a conexão com a base de dados?

Comment: A connexão é feita atraves de uma connection string.

Comment: Você pode mostrar a connection string ou ela contém informação protegida? Pois provavelmente a causa desse comportamento, que descreveu,está aí.

Comment: Apresente a sua string de conexão... quando você encontrar ela verá que essa essa pergunta não faz sentido nenhum.

Comment: <add connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=outraDB;Integrated Security=true" name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> Como disse anteriormente esta connection string aponta para uma base de dados que eu criei, mas se eu apagar essa base de dados a app funciona na mesma e contem os dados guardados anteriormente.

Comment: Se a sua aplicação não está apontando para a base `outraDB` no `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` é porque você está utilizando outra string de conexão configurada em outro lugar... ou você está esperando que o servidor acesse a sua máquina local enquanto ele está olhando para ele mesmo...

Answer (score 3):

Você não deve utilizar o localDB no ambiente de produção, ele é um recurso destinado apenas para o ambiente de desenvolvimento. Por padrão o .mdf dele é criado dentro da pasta do usuário em `C:\Users\Nome_do_usuario`.

Após publicar a sua aplicação no IIS aponte a string de conexão para uma instância real do seu SQL Server. Que se estiver rodando na mesma máquina que o ISS pode começar com `.\`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<add connectionString="Server=.\NomeDaInstancia;Database=outraDB;Integrated Security=true" name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Sim, eu sei que os ficheiros .MDF ficam nessa pasta, mas mesmo depois de os apagar a app funciona na mesma e tem dados guardados. Como sei qual o nome da instância real do meu Server ? Lamento a minha ignorância mas não percebo muito de IIS ou SQL Server. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Onde você fez a publicação da base? Onde está rodando o seu servidor do SQL Server (endereço)?

Comment: A aplicação foi publicada numa pasta especifica no servidor. O Sql está rodando no mesmo servidor da aplicação.

Comment: E como você se conecta nesse SQL Server que está instalado no servidor?

Comment: Através do Sql Server Management Studio..

Comment: Usando qual endereço e credenciais?

Comment: (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB | autenticação do windows

Comment: Então me parece que você não tem um SQL Server instalado e configurado de forma adequada no seu servidor

Comment: Resolvido. Alguém disse aqui, acho eu, que não se deve usar localdb para aplicações que estão publicadas no IIS, e talves tenha sido esse o problema, honestamente não posso dizer com toda a certeza se foi isso que causou o problema ou não. Para resolver o problema instalei o SqlServer 2017, e depois de definir um login para um novo user e criar uma nova base de dados tudo funcionou na perfeição. Obrigado o todos.

Comment: É o que eu disse na minha resposta...